# Printing expressions using command Print and Manipulate in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need help with this task:

I am asked to print the real and the imaginary part of `Exp[u*I]`, where `phi` goes from `0` to `2*pi`, using command Manipulate and Print.

I have tried sth like that:

```
Manipulate[Print[{Re[Exp[u* I]], Im[Exp[u*I]]}], {u, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

*But it doesn't work. Where am I doing a mistake?*

Comment: `pi` should be `Pi`.

Comment: I made a typo here. In Mathematica it is all right.

Comment: Then what is the problem?